# Making a Cyclic Graph Appear Python

Tags: python, excel, plot, canopy

I am trying to make a simple python code to display two cyclic graphs but I am having trouble with not getting it to display. The window pops up with the x/y graph displayed but not lines. Just white space. It does, strangely, work when I use *r and *b but I need continuous lines. In my excel sheet the data is within columns A, B, C, & D. (I am using Canopy.)

```
import pylab as plt
import csv
with open('Book2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for column in data:
        X1 = column[0]
        X2 = column[1]
        Y1 = column[3]
        Y2 = column[4]

        plt.plot(Y1, Y2, 'b')
        plt.plot(X1, X2, 'r')
        plt.show()
```

But if I directly input the data into the code it works fine:

```
import pylab as plt

X1 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5]
X2 = [2,4,6,8,6,4,2,4,6,8,6,4,2]
Y1 = [1,3,5,7,9,7,5,3,1,3,5,7,9]
Y2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

plt.plot(Y1, Y2, 'b')
plt.plot(X1, X2, 'r')
plt.show()
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: And if you remove the indentations before the last lines (the `plt.` ones)

Answer (score 0):

1. Print out your data to see if it is as expected.
2. You refer to columns A-D but your code looks at columns 0,1, 3,4 (skipping one)?
3. Move plt.show() out of the `for` loop